# Adding a script to Google Forms to identify incorrect phone numbers

Tags: google-apps-script, google-forms, phone-number

I currently use Google Forms as a way for applicants to submit their forms. One of the fields that is required is for their contact information. In my country phone numbers have 11 digits.

Is there a script that I can use that will not accept a number if it does not contain 11 digits and display an error message, like "Incorrect number, please check and try again"?

The number format should be `09xxxxxxxxx`.

Answer (score 2):

One option is to use Google Forms validation tools - not as much control, but far easier than a script.   They're under Advanced Settings for a text field.   The picture below is looking for any 11-digit number, but you could make it more specific    eg  between 09000000000 and 100000000000.

[image]